Let $u,v \in V$ such that $\phi(u) = 0 \implies \phi(v) = 0\quad \forall\,\phi \in V^{*}$. Show that $v = ku$ for some $k \in \mathbb{K}$.
Let $u,v \in V$ be vectors such that for every linear function $\phi \in V^{*} \implies \phi(u) = 0 \implies \phi(v) = 0$ holds. We need to show that $v = ku$ for some scalar $k \in \mathbb{K}$.
In other words, consider the set $U$ defined as:
$$
U = \{\phi \in V^{*} : \phi(u) = 0\}.
$$
We aim to demonstrate that if there exists a vector $v \in V$ such that:
$$
\phi(v) = 0\quad\forall\, \phi \in U,
$$
then $v$ must be of the form $v = ku$ for some $k \in \mathbb{K}$.
Recall that $V^{*}$ denotes the set of all linear functionals from $V$ to $\mathbb{K}$:
$$
f: V \to \mathbb{K},
$$
where $f \in V^{*}$.

What have you tried?

I attempted to express a generic $\phi \in U$ applied to $u$ using the basis elements of $V$. We have: $u = a_1 u_1 + \dots + a_n u_n$ where $u_i$ are the basis elements of $V$. Applying $\phi$ to $u$ gives: $\phi(u) = \phi(a_1 u_1 + \dots + a_n u_n). $ this expression can be expanded to: $\phi(u) = a_1 \phi(u_1) + a_2 \phi(u_2) + \dots + a_n \phi(u_n). $
For $v = ku$, it is straightforward to see that $\phi(v) = k\phi(u) = 0$. The challenge lies in demonstrating the uniqueness of $v$ such that $\phi(v) = 0$.

$U$ has codimension $1$, see this duplicate, so the claim follows.

Thank you, I didn't notice that. I'll follow up on this. Thanks

Choose $\eta$ such that $\eta(u) \ne 0$ (otherwise $u=v=0$) and let $k= {\eta(v) \over \eta(u)}$. Then $f(v-ku) = 0$ for all $f \in V^*$.
